# Is there a compiler for standard HTML that allows includes without a server-side language?

Tags: html, compilation, include

I've recently had a couple of projects that required delivering standard HTML files, each of which has a lot of common markup in the header and footer of the page.

I use SASS for CSS and love that I can include one .scss file into another, and still end up with a single .css file.

I'm hopeful that there is a similar compiler for HTML, but I haven't been able to find one.

I though HAML might be the ticket, but it doesn't seem to have include functionality.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a server-side language to generate the HTML, then output to a file.

Comment: or just use server side includes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I'm going to be sending files back and forth to our client many times and want to avoid the overhead of outputting 50 or more files each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is Jade:

https://github.com/visionmedia/jade

Simplifies your HTML and allows compiled includes.

Comment: Great suggestion. I didn't see that Jade can do includes and can fairly simply allow raw HTML in the jade file.  This looks like my best bet. Thanks!